# Ошибка выделения памяти (reallock)

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

Здравствуйте! Сейчас пытаюсь писать рогалик на си, параллельно разбираюсь с работой с памятью (очень весело, после питона и шарпа).

Есть такой код:
`field` - "двумерный" массив, в котором хранится лабиринт
`width`и `height`, я думаю, понятно
`sizeret` длинна возвращаемого массива точек

```
point *find_connectors(char *field, int width, int height, int *sizeret)
{
    point *ret;
    int size = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x<width; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y<height; y++)
        {
            char upper  = get(x, y+1, field, width, height);
            char bottom = get(x, y-1, field, width, height);
            char left   = get(x-1, y, field, width, height);
            char right  = get(x+1, y, field, width, height);

            if(right  != left && left    != ' '  && right  != ' ' ||
               bottom != upper && bottom != ' '  && upper  != ' ' ||
               right  != upper && right  != ' '  && upper  != ' ' ||
               right  != bottom && right != ' '  && bottom != ' ' ||
               left   != upper && left   != ' '  && upper  != ' ' ||
               left   != bottom && left  != ' '  && upper  != ' ')
            {
                if(ret == NULL)
                {
                    size++;
                    ret = malloc(sizeof(point));

                    if(!ret)
                    {
                        printf("\n\n\n Bad memory error! Line %d\n\n\n", __LINE__);
                        exit(1);
                    }

                    ret[size-1] = new_point(x, y);
                }
                else
                {
                    size++;
                    ret = realloc(ret, sizeof(point)*size);

                    if(!ret)
                    {
                        printf("\n\n\n Bad memory error! Line %d, size %d\n\n\n", __LINE__, size);
                        exit(1);
                    }

                    ret[size-1] = new_point(x, y);
                }
            }
        }       

    *sizeret = size;

    return ret;
}
```

Что он делает: он проходится по всему массиву символов `field`, и ищет там точки, в соседних от которых находятся разные символы. Это нужно для генерации лабиринта. Эти точки заносятся в массив `ret`, его длинна в `size`, а потом в `sizeret`.

Но при вызове данной функции стабильно получаю ошибку (в ветке `else`). Алгоритм, вроде, рабочий, проблемы начались после того, как я вынес его в отдельную функцию.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас переменная `ret` никак не инициализируется. А логика кода внутри цикла завязана на

```
if (ret == NULL)
```

В результате у вас в `ret` изначально содержится какой-то ненулевой мусор, который сразу же приводит к выбору ветки `else`, где этот мусор затем попадает в `realloc`. `realloc` падает.

Можно, конечно, просто заменить `if (ret == NULL)` на `if (size == 0)`, ибо `size` вы проинициализировать не забыли. Но лучше поступить по-другому.

Во-первых, проинициализируйте ваш `ret`

```
point *ret = NULL;
```

Во-вторых, на самом деле ваше деление на две ветки - `malloc` и `realloc` - лишняя работа, часто встречающаяся в коде у новичков. Они почему-то верят, что сначала надо обязательно сделать `malloc`, а только потом можно будет делать `realloc`.

На самом же деле в функцию `realloc` можно передавать null-указатель в качестве первого параметра. В таком случае функция `realloc` будет эквивалентна функции `malloc`. То есть вам в вашем коде, если изначально инициализировать `ret` в `NULL`, то проверку `if (ret == NULL)` и всю первую ветку кода (c `malloc`) можно будет убрать вообще. Вторая ветка уже сама обработает все случаи правильно.

Comment: С одним моментом, что *x = realloc(x, ...* -- это плохая идея.

Comment: @0andriy: `x = realloc(x,...` - это плохая идея если вы собираетесь как-то "восстанавливаться" из этой ситуации и продолжать выполнение функции/программы. Если же на возврат null из `realloc` вы собираетесь тут же на месте аварийно останавливать выполнение, то ничего плохого в этой идее нет. Автор, как видите, решил пойти именно по второму пути.

Comment: ...что не отменяет плохого стиля программирования.

Comment: @0andriy: Отнюдь. Никакого безусловного плохого стиля в `x = realloc(x,...` нет. Обзывать это "плохим стилем" вне контекста - это типичный карго-культ. "Плохим стилем" можно назвать манеру выходить из функции "сразу на месте"  через `exit`, но в определенном классе приложений это вполне уместно.

Comment: Это как раз типичный случай плохого стиля, и вот почему: научится человек так писать, потом на автомате где-нибудь да и ляпнет таким в продакшн. Спасибо, не надо.

Comment: @0andriy: Если сотрудники - coding monkeys, результаты трудов которых  определяются их поведением "на автомате", то возможно это и так... На в такой ситуации "в продакшене" будут проблемы *намного* посерьезнее, чем какой-то несчастный `realloc`. Это правило про `realloc` - это что-то из области того, что вдалбливают студентам-первокурсникам для создания в их головах правильных изначальных приоритетов. Инициализация, образно выражаясь.

Comment: А уже на втором курсе им с самого начала говорят - "ребята, то что вам вдалбливали на первом курсе - конечно, важно, но в реальном программировании все несколько сложнее и даже наоборот...". Поэтому когда я встречаю вроде бы уже оформившегося программиста, который тем не менее мыслит вот таким вот догмами и сыплет налево и направо "единственно верными правилами" ("one true rule"), то первая моя мысль: "отчислили сразу после первого курса".

Comment: Большинство программистов или "обезьянки", или последователи карго-культа.

Comment: @AnT спасибо, мне казалось, что я где-то читал про то, что можно обойтись одним `realloc`.  Вы говорите, что плохим тоном может считаться выход с помощью `exit()`. А как поступить правильнее? И что считают "хорошим стилем" те, кто считают `reallc` плохим?

Answer (score 1):

При определении переменной без инициализации происходит ее инициализация по умолчанию.Значение объекта по умолчанию зависит от того, где именно он определяется.Переменные определенные вне тела функции инициализируются значением 0.Определенные в теле функции остаются неинициализированным.
 point *ret=nullptr;
Инициализируй явно и будет тебе счастье)

Comment: Язык С. `nullptr`?

Comment: возможно уже стандарт С++.Попробуй тогда point *ret=0;

Comment: Что значит "уже стандарт С++"?

Comment: nullptr появился в С++

Comment: Это классно. Он уже шесть лет назад там появился. Но при чем здесь С++ вообще, если программа написана на С?